# Can't get jQuery Validation plugin error message to go away

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-validate

I have a set of radio buttons within a div (parent1) that is shown or hidden via javascript according to other settings on the page.

```
<div class="parent1">
<input type="radio" name="legal_14" id="legal_14a" value="1" class="legal_14"/> <label for="legal_14a">option 1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="legal_14" id="legal_14b" value="2" class="legal_14"/> <label for="legal_14b">option 2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="legal_14" id="legal_14c" value="3" class="legal_14"/> <label for="legal_14c">option 3</label><br/>
<span class="val-error"></span><br/>
</div>
```

I only want to validate the radio buttons when they are visible.  So I have a dependency-callback to handle this situation like thus:

```
 "legal_14": {
  required: function() {if (!$('.parent1').is(':visible')) {console.log(false); return false;} else if ($("input[name='legal_14']:checked").length > 0) {console.log(false); return false;} else {console.log(true); return true;}}},
...
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  element.nextAll(".val-error").first().html(error.html());
},
success: function(label) {
  label.nextAll(".val-error").first().html();
}
```

So this works just fine for displaying the error message under the correct circumstances (i.e. when the buttons are visible, but not clicked).  The problem is that once I select one of the radio buttons, the console.log properly returns false, but the error message does not go away.  I have a similar dependency callback elsewhere that doesn't depend on visibility that works just fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, this should work:

```
if($(".parent1").is(":visible"))
{
    // do validation 

   // return message 
}
```

Comment: That's basically what I am doing, except I am also checking whether one of the checkboxes is actually checked.  I get the correct return value from my function, it just doesn't seem to clear the error message.